# Is there any Cassandra PCAP analyser

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, pcap

I wanna to extract CQL from Cassandra traffic!

Is there any program or tools to take a Cassandra pcap file and extract Queries and other information from the traffic? I read about [wirelatency](https://github.com/circonus-labs/wirelatency), but I don't wanna run third party program on Cassandra machines.

Any experience can be helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wireshark should have [built-in support for CQL native protocol](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/troubleshooting/use_tools.html#packet-capture).  See [Cassandra documentation as well](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/troubleshooting/use_tools.html#packet-capture).